# How to shutdown express server task in gulp

Tags: express, gulp

I have a gulp task that launches express server and after the task is done I want to shut the server down. How can I do it in gulp?

Comment: can you please put task code here which starts express.

Answer (score 1):

So I was able to shutdown server by having a callback in the gulp task that gets called when the task is done and I invoke `server.close()` where `server` is set to `var server = (require('express')()).listen(3000);`

`gulp.run('sometask', function() {
   server.close();//when task is done server is shutdown
});`